# Laravel 5.1 - Return First Error From FormRequest Validation

Tags: php, arrays, validation, laravel-5.1

I have the following form request:

```
class FileRequest extends Request
{

   public function authorize()
   {
      return true;
   }

   public function rules()
   {

      $rules = [];

      if($this->file_type == 'image')
         $rules['file'] = 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif|max:244|image_size:>=360,>=180';
    else
         $rules['file'] = 'required|mimes:doc,pdf,docx,txt,rtf|max:1000';

      return $rules;

   }

   public function messages()
   {
      $messages = [
        'file.image_size' => 'The image size is incorrect.'
      ];

      return $messages;
   }

   public function response(array $errors)
   {
        $content = "<textarea data-type=\"application/json\">{\"ok\": false, \"message\": \"" . $errors[0] . "\" }</textarea>";
         return response($content);

    }



}
```

How do i return the first error from the errors array.

When I manually create a validator I'm able to do the following: `$validator->errors()->first()` but this doesn't work when using a FormRequest class. Doing `errors[0]` simply gives me an offset exception error.

I'm using an iframe submit which is why I need to return the response as above.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do the following:

```
$errors['file'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need use the validator system from laravel.
After that you could use : $validator->messages() ; for have all the errors.
If you use $validator->messages()[0]; you gonna have the first message.

I suggest you something like that

```
     public function store(Request $request)
    {
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' =>'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif|max:244|image_size:>=360,>=180';

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    // Store the file
}
```

Comment: I know how do it by making a validator but i'm using a form request class and I want to achieve it inside my form request class.

Comment: protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
{
return $validator->errors()->all();
}                                                                                                                       Have you try this?